# Ferrite rod antenna matching network for SA606 RF input

Tags: rf, impedance-matching

I'm trying to hook a ferrite rod antenna up to an NXP SA606 mixer (https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/SA606.pdf) and I'm not quite sure if I'm interfacing correctly with the matching network. I think the circuit diagram (Figure 16) on page 15 of the SA606 datasheet assumes an antenna with a coaxial connector. I don't know how to substitute an antenna with a coaxial connector with a ferrite rod antenna. The ultimate goal is to make use of the chip's RSSI feature.

As of right now I have it set up like this...

[image]

...where L1 is the ferrite rod wound up with magnetic wire. L1 and C1 set the resonant frequency to 457kHz per the equation F=1/(2pi*sqrt(LC)). The part that I'm unsure of is the input impedance matching. I followed the steps shown on page 7 of an application note on the SA605 (https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN1994.pdf) to calculate L2, C2, and C3 to also resonate at 457kHz. But with that Tapped-C network is it necessary to terminate the antenna with the 50ohm resistor, R1? Previously I was trying to do this with the Analog Devices AD8307 Log Amp (https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8307.pdf) and I set the antenna side up the same exact way trying to follow Figure 32 on page 17 of the datasheet, hence the 50ohm resistor. Here's how I had it setup with the AD8307...
[image]

...where C2 and C3 set the high-pass frequency to around 6.3kHz per the equation F=1/(pi*R*C).

Have I done this correctly? Or am I way off?

Comment: You don't need to worry about impedance matching at 457 kHz.

Comment: Losing a lot of RF power to 50 ohms might be done if you value dynamic range more than weak-signal performance. Your interest in RSSI suggests this is true, but your ultimate goal is unclear. Do you consider **tuning** that ferrite antenna to different frequencies important? That will influence your matching network.

Comment: @Andyaka I watched a Youtube video about impedance matching and the guy mentioned that a matching network should be used for power transmission. I assumed that even though 457kHz is a low frequency, I'm still trying to read the power level picked up by the antenna. Am I off base?

Comment: @glen_geek Yes. The ferrite rod is tuned at those values. The 473 pF cap, C1, is actually a capacitor with a trimmer capacitor in parallel. I just put it in LTSpice as one cap for simplicity. Dynamic range isn't super important. This project is for avalanche beacons. The buried beacon transmits at 457kHz and the receiver ferrite rod is tuned to that resonant freq. The RSSI should grow as the distance between TX and RX beacons decreases. The dynamic range should only need to be (+/-) 2-3kHz.

Comment: If you try and match the rod output with 50 ohm you'll kill the Q of the circuit and make tuning very unselective indeed.

Comment: How do you intend to use the mixer? As a simple gain stage (with local oscillator set to 0 Hz with DC offset)? With so much overall gain @ 456 kHz, this chip will be *very hard* to keep stable. You might consider matching ferrite antenna to I.F. amplifier input.

Comment: @glen_geek Interesting. And just skip the Mixer section altogether? As I have it right now I use the configuration in the first photo of my post for the RF Input Pin and then I have the LO set to 912KHz with 455kHz ceramic filters off of MIXER_OUT and IF_AMP_OUT. Another thing I can't seem to figure out is what to set the amplitude and offset of the LO to.